# hibernate: log the function that ends up generating a SQL call

Tags: hibernate, logging

I have encountered a problem about logging in Hibernate, and I couldn't find a solution on the web.

I want to log the function name that ends up generating a SQL statement.

For example, I have a function `myFunction()` that calls

`Person.setAddress()`

, which results in a SQL:

`insert into Person (address) values (X street)`.

Can I use some logging library to log the name of the function(`myFunction()`), since it results in generating a SQL call?

I was playing around with adding a log4j appender to org.hibernate.SQL, but it didn't give me the result that I want.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This [link](http://pokurinaresh.wordpress.com/2013/03/23/hibernate-logging-sqls-executed-by-a-method/) might help you. You can take it a step further and utilize AOP for better practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, although I was trying to avoid using AspectJ because I cannot inject an aspect to every function.